# SVG fill color change after resize make the svg invisible

Tags: jquery-ui, svg, filter, resize

I have an inline svg with a filter applied to it for shadow effect on the right and buttom of the SVG .

```
<div id="d78" class="drag" style="width: 52px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 138 138" >
       <defs>
           <filter id="blurFilter2" y="-10" height="40" x="-10" width="150">
             <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" dx="3" dy="3" result="offset2"></feOffset>
             <feGaussianBlur in="offset2" stdDeviation="3"  result="blur2">/feGaussianBlur>

           <feMerge>
               <feMergeNode in="blur2"></feMergeNode>
               <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
           </feMerge>
           </filter>
        </defs>
            <rect class="rrfNode" fill="#4B4F54"  x="0" y="0" width="130" height="130" style="filter: url(#blurFilter2); " />
</svg>
```

The container div is draggable and resizeable through jquery UI plugin . The container div has a color picker icon attached to it which when clicked displays the color palette and on choosing any color the svg rect changes to that particular color for which I have written some jquery .

Now when I resize the svg and then try to use the color picker to change color of the svg rect , the svg just disappears from view even though I can see that the svg color is getting set when I inspect the element in the Chrome browser .
  The jquery code to change color is :

```
$(document).on('changeColor','.fa-eyedropper',function(e) {
        $(this).parents(".ui-draggable").find(".rrfNode").css({ fill:                        color.toHex()});
});
```

The invisible svg reappears again after I resize the svg .

When I delete the filter this problem gets resolved . But I need to keep both the resize and the color picker along with the filter .

I suspect that it is a problem with the filter , but I cannot figure that out . After searching and trying to solve this bug for 2 days I am posing this question . Please help .

Comment: Please create an [MCVE]{http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: well I don't know if this is the issue - but you need to add "filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" to your filter element if you're going to use viewbox units as your filter dimensions;

Answer (score 1):

Found out the reason behind this strange behaviour . The filter id in all the svg images were the same so any change to any of the svgs would result in the shadows of other svg images disappearing along with the content of the images, in effect the image will disappear. I changed the filter ids for the svg images , such that all svgs have unique filter ids and that has solved my problem . It was a very silly mistake on my part.